# Unable to show image in listview by imageloader class

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview

I have used view in my application. I wants to show image in my list by using POST method. I got the image url by POST method but unable to show it in list. some part of my code snippet is here....

```
 private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Home1.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait....");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler1 sh = new ServiceHandler1(apikey, latitude, longitude);


            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler1.POST);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);


            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                        String username = c.getString(TAG_USERNAME);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                        String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                        String contact_number = c.getString(TAG_CONTACT_NUMBER);
                        String postalcode = c.getString(TAG_POSTAL_CODE);
                        String image = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);
                        Log.v("as.",image);

                        ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
                        ImageView Profileimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
                        imageLoader.DisplayImage(image, Profileimage);


                        // tmp hashmap for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

                        contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        contact.put(TAG_IMAGE, image);
                        contact.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                        // contact.put(TAG_ADDRESS, address);
                        contact.put(TAG_ADDRESS, address);
                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contact.put(TAG_USERNAME, username);
                        contact.put(TAG_POSTAL_CODE, postalcode);
                        contact.put(TAG_CONTACT_NUMBER, contact_number);

                        contactList.add(contact);


                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    Home1.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item1, new String[]{TAG_EMAIL, TAG_USERNAME, TAG_ADDRESS, TAG_POSTAL_CODE, TAG_CONTACT_NUMBER,
            }, new int[]{
                   R.id.company, R.id.description, R.id.address, R.id.operating_hours, R.id.contact});





            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }
```

I have used image loader class for converting the image url... guys please help me

please suggest me how can I parse image in postExecute()...

```
  @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    Home1.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item1, new String[]{TAG_EMAIL, TAG_USERNAME, TAG_ADDRESS, TAG_POSTAL_CODE, TAG_CONTACT_NUMBER,
            }, new int[]{
                   R.id.company, R.id.description, R.id.address, R.id.operating_hours, R.id.contact});


            ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
            ImageView Profileimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(TAG_IMAGE, Profileimage);



            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Which library are you using for ImageLoader? Try to move the imageLoader.DisplayImage(image, Profileimage); inside onPostExecute() method.

Comment: @ProkashSarkar   when i used it in Post() method it gives  java.lang.NullPointerException ........

Comment: If you already have Adapter set while you call to AsyncTask, try to call to getListAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged() instead creating new one.

Comment: Are you using any library?

Comment: @ProkashSarkar i used this code......   http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/

Comment: Have you added the android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom `Listview` adapter to achieve this task. Please check [loading-image-asynchronously-in-android-listview](http://loading-image-asynchronously-in-android-listview) link to create one. In your post execute method you have to create object of adapter and then pass your `contactList` array list which consist images URL.

In the link you will get full code of showing images in `listview` with code of downloading image using `Imageloader` library.

Let me know if it helps.